# How to share Android Library project that contain JNI code?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, eigen

I have a main Android project and I would like to use a library called Eigen.  The integration has already been done here https://github.com/james34602/Android-Linear-Algebra-manipulation-using-Eigen

But what I was wondering what is best way to pull this into my project?  Should I create a module and reference this whole other project? Or just duplicate the JNI code within my own project? Seems like the place for modules but just how would I pull in JNI code with a module?

Answer (score 0):

> Should I create a module and reference this whole other project?

No.

> Or just duplicate the JNI code within my own project?

Also no. You have no rights to use that code, as the developer of that code did not apply any sort of license to it.

Instead, use that sample project as a guide for your own independent implementation. Whether you just put that in your Android app module or in a separate library module is up to you. For example, if you planned on having N apps use that same library, separating the code out into a library module will make that easier.

Comment: You may also ask the creator of that project under which license he wants to publish its code.